# Ansdroid Studio, Layout Inspector, What is dashed rectangle?

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, debugging, layout

Could you please tell me what the dashed rectangle means in the below screenshot of Android Studio Layout Inspector? it looks like some layer. But I could not debug it.

My app has some layers on the screen at some point which disable clicking on the screen. I wanted to debug it. when I click on the dashed line. Nothing comes in attributes. Also, the rotation of the screen ( in the layout inspector) is also disabled. it could be some animation.

What are possible components dashed line represents?

Comment: where is the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is Andorid UI "bonus", called `android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"`attribute, that is enabled by default (documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled)).

In short - system by default automatically adds "statefull" background for focusable views, and in focused state they are slightly dimmed. In layout inspector such "statefull" background in focused state will be shown as "dashed rectangle".
When you click on the view focused state is dropped and "dashed rectangle" goes away.

To fix the issue you should add `android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"` for the corresponding view or do the same from the code.